# cannot overwrite files with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to overwrite files i created in php
when i'm using file_put_contents i receive 0 of "x" bytes written

with the function below that uses fwrite i get the error the file is not writable.

the permissions are 777 (including the directories)

there is no problem creating files, the problem is when i try to modify them.

can anyone figure what is the problem?

```
function update_body($body)
{
    $URL = $_REQUEST["URL"];
    $filename = $URL;
    $somecontent = $body;

    if (is_writable($filename)) 
    {
        if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w')) 
        {
            echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
            exit;
        }

        if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) 
        {
            echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
            exit;
        }

        echo "Success, wrote ($somecontent) to file ($filename)";

        fclose($handle);

    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "The file $filename is not writable";
    }
}
```

the procedure where i create the file

```
function save_body($body)
{
    $datearr = getdate(); //get date array, use date for folder, time for filename
    $current_date = $datearr['year'].$datearr['mon'].$datearr['mday'];
    $current_time = $datearr['hours'].$datearr['minutes'].$datearr['seconds'];

    // create directory according the date
    if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/articles/'.$current_date)) 
        mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/articles/'.$current_date, 0777, true);

    // write the file
    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/articles/'.$current_date.'/'.$current_time.'.txt',"w");
    fwrite($fp,$body);
    fclose($fp);
    return  $current_date.'/'.$current_time;
}
```

Comment: how do you create the files?

Comment: As a first guess I would suggest that perhaps the file you're looking at is not the one PHP is trying to write to.  Could you include in your answer the output, the error message.

Comment: "when i'm using file_put_contents" - I don't see a call of  file_put_contents in your code.

Comment: i created the file using fopen and fwrite also

Comment: i deleted the call to file_put_contents -user4035 ,The file , h.t.t.p.:././myaddress.com/articles/2013720/83745.txt is not writable -couling

Comment: i'd like to see the procedure where you create the file

Comment: added to the post Sebas

Comment: thank you. What about echoing the $_REQUEST["URL"] part to be sure you're writing on the good file?

Comment: did an echo, the $URL holds the address to the file i am trying to change Sebas

Comment: which php version? is safe_mode enabled?
perhaps it's a problem with uid compare check when opening files

Comment: @atikot, you could try using relative path instead ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/articles/ ...)

Comment: @Sebas , will try now

Comment: you should not pass a URL, but a filename in your server directory structure in the form /home/usr/content/articles/bladeebladeebla.txt

Comment: @KevinHorst Horst  PHP 5.3 ,safe_mode Off(local value) Off (master value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

As @Sebas said, try to use a relative path (../../../articles) or wherever your folder is instead of

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

Have a nice day!